# Errors when compiling library in command line

Tags: windows, visual-studio, compiler-errors, nmake

I am trying to compile this library: http://www.mega-nerd.com/SRC/win32.html . but I am having some trouble. Here's what happens:

```
C:\libsamplerate-0.1.8>make
    1 file(s) copied.
    1 file(s) copied.

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 10.00.30319.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

    link.exe /nologo /dll /incremental:no /libpath:""C:\Program Files (x86)\
Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE"\Lib" /pdb:"libsamplerate-0.pdb" /impli
b:".\libsamplerate-0.lib" /machine:I386 /out:"libsamplerate-0.dll" /def:".\Win32
\libsamplerate-0.def" ".\src\samplerate.obj"  ".\src\src_linear.obj"  ".\src\src
_zoh.obj"  ".\src\src_sinc.obj"
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'Files.obj'
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0
\VC\BIN\link.exe"' : return code '0x49d'
Stop.
```

I run vcvars32.bat prior to attempting to compile, I think I have all the right folders in my path variable, but I'm new to this so I'm not entirely sure. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

You are having a quoting issue with the line:
`/libpath:""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE"\Lib"`

Should be:
`/libpath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\Lib"`

Answer (score 2):

You get error: "LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'Files.obj'"
Because the linker thinks you are adding file "Files" as one of input libraries.
This comes from "C:\Program Files (x86)" (see the "Files"?) ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Check if [kb 815645](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815645) doesn't help:

> #### You receive a "`fatal error LNK1181`" error message when you build a Managed C++ application

```
fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'C:\Program.obj'
```

> #### Scenario 2:
>
> The linker error `LNK1181` may also occur if you add an unqualified file to the Additional Dependencies project property, and that file does not exist in any of the search directories that are defined in the `LIB` environment variable or the `/LIBPATH` project property.
>   You may add the directory that contains library file to the `LIBPATH` to resolve the problem:
>
> - In Solution Explorer, right-click the project, and then click Properties.
> - In the Property Pages dialog box, expand Linker, and then click General.
>     In the Additional Library Directories field, specify the required library path.